# AngularJS date filter in React

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, date-formatting, datefilter

In **AngularJS**, one could display datetime strings in various formats using date filters:

```
<p>Date: {{ "2017-02-10T12:10:00.000Z" | date : "fullDate" }}</p>
```

and that would render:

```
Date: Friday, February 10, 2017
```

Is there such a thing as a date filter in **React**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of npm package `moment` to achieve what you want.

Install it like:

```
npm install --save moment
```

And then import in your React component like:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

You can use it like:

```
const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss');
```

**[Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)**

Comment: great answer, here

Comment: is there any default filter in reactjs for the same ?

Comment: @PardeepJain, no there isn't a default filter for it